# How to get all the files form a directory where name does not contains 0?

Tags: c#, xml

Recently I have built a small converter that converts txt data to xml in a certain structure , I choose a folder and the program loops through all the files in that folder and write in a `XML` format all together in one xml document.

In the folder I have data names like:

Data.0001.txt

Data.0002.txt

Data.0003.txt

Data.0004.txt

Data.txt

and so on

I want only the files that dose NOT contain zeros in them because ones with zeros are just a back up copy for the others , and i have over 6000 file i can't filter them manually

**Here is my code so far**

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog SelectFolder = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        String path = @"C:\newpages";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Pages");

        if (SelectFolder.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var txt = string.Empty;
            string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles((SelectFolder.SelectedPath));
            int i = 1;
            foreach (string path1 in Files)
            {              
                String filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension((path1));
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path1))
                {
                    txt = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    XmlElement id = doc.CreateElement("Page.id");
                    id.SetAttribute("Page.Nr", i.ToString());
                    id.SetAttribute("Pagetitle",  filename);
                    XmlElement name = doc.CreateElement("PageContent");
                    XmlCDataSection cdata = doc.CreateCDataSection(txt);
                    name.AppendChild(cdata);
                    id.AppendChild(name);  // page id appenndchild         
                    root.AppendChild(id);  // roots appenedchild
                    doc.AppendChild(root); //Main root

                }
             i++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("finished");
        Console.ReadKey();

        doc.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(path, ".xml"));

    }
}
```

Any help would be really nice guys

Comment: Cant it be as simple as in your `foreach` loop `if(!filename.Contains("0"))`

Comment: @AfnanAhmad yes actually i was so desperate that i didn't even thought of that it should ".0" because there is always a "." , thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetFiles` returns the name of a file in a specified directory. Its return type is `string[]` so you can easily apply a `Where` to filter the `file` names as follow:-

```
 var files = Directory.GetFiles("PathToYourDirec").Where(name => !name.Contains("0"));
```

Comment: didn't know it was that easy thanks worked , all the others worked as well

Comment: @PassionateCoder Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

On the string filename you could make sure it doesn't contain "0"

```
if(!filename.Contains("0"))
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On the `Files` variable you can use a regex to filter out the filenames which contains only letters

```
var reg = new Regex(@"^([^0-9]*)$");
var files = Directory.GetFiles("path-to-folder")
                     .Where(path => reg.IsMatch(path))
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: i tried to use Regex at first but it didn't work for me , i'll try again with the code you wrote thanks man

Comment: No problem. Please upvote or accept if it solves your problem.

Comment: i did up vote but seems like that i can't up vote sorry i have less than 15 reputation :D  kinda new , but that's always to understand these regular expression

Comment: No Problem, @PassionateCoder! :)

Answer (score 0):

The whole code can be largely simplified while solving this issue. You don't need a StreamReader just to read the whole file, and you may as well get the filename early and filter instead of going into the foreach and filtering :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog SelectFolder = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    String path = @"C:\newpages";

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Pages");

    if (SelectFolder.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Don't declare txt here, you're overwriting and only using it in a nested loop, declare it as you use it there
        // var txt = string.Empty;

        //string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles((SelectFolder.SelectedPath));
        // Change to getting FileInfos
        var Files = new DirectoryInfo(SelectFolder.SelectedPath).GetFiles()
            // Only keep those who don't contain a zero in file name
            .Where(f=>!f.Name.Contains("0"));
        int i = 1;
        foreach (var file in Files)
        {
            //String filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension((path1));

            // Don't need a StreamReader not a using block, just read the whole file at once with File.ReadAllText
            //using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path1))
            //{
                //txt = sr.ReadToEnd();

                var txt = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);
                XmlElement id = doc.CreateElement("Page.id");
                id.SetAttribute("Page.Nr", i.ToString());
                id.SetAttribute("Pagetitle", file.FullName);
                XmlElement name = doc.CreateElement("PageContent");
                XmlCDataSection cdata = doc.CreateCDataSection(txt);
                name.AppendChild(cdata);
                id.AppendChild(name);  // page id appenndchild         
                root.AppendChild(id);  // roots appenedchild
                doc.AppendChild(root); //Main root
            //}
            i++;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("finished");
    Console.ReadKey();

    doc.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(path, ".xml"));

}
```

I would also advise not working with the XML api you're using but with the more recent and simpler linq to XML one as that would simplify creating your elements too, see bellow a very simplified version of the whole code as i'd have writen it with LINQ and XElements

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog SelectFolder = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    String path = @"C:\newpages";

    var root = new XElement("Pages");

    if (SelectFolder.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var FilesXML = new DirectoryInfo(SelectFolder.SelectedPath).GetFiles()
            .Where(f => !f.Name.Contains("0"))
            // Note that the index is 0 based, if you want to start with 1 just replace index by index+1 in Page.Nr
            .Select((file, index) => 
                new XElement("Page.id",
                    new XAttribute("Page.Nr",index),
                    new XAttribute("Pagetitle",file.FullName),
                    new XElement("PageContent",
                        new XCData(File.ReadAllText(file.FullName))
                    )));
        // Here we already have all your XML ready, just need to add it to the root

        root.Add(FilesXML);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("finished");
    Console.ReadKey();

    root.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(path, ".xml"));

}
```

Comment: this is very well written , i don't have much experience with programming in general , i'll try this code right away , thanks a lot man

Answer (score -1):

You can try this, but I would suggest if you change the logic of creating name of backup files. It should not depend on "0" as character in it but instead of that firm text like "backup" should be mentioned in file name.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog SelectFolder = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        String path = @"C:\newpages";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Pages");

        if (SelectFolder.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var txt = string.Empty;
            string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles((SelectFolder.SelectedPath));

            int i = 1;
            foreach (string path1 in Files)
            {
                String filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension((path1));

                if (!filename.Contains(".0"))
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path1))
                    {
                        txt = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        XmlElement id = doc.CreateElement("Page.id");
                        id.SetAttribute("Page.Nr", i.ToString());
                        id.SetAttribute("Pagetitle",  filename);
                        XmlElement name = doc.CreateElement("PageContent");
                        XmlCDataSection cdata = doc.CreateCDataSection(txt);
                        name.AppendChild(cdata);
                        id.AppendChild(name);  // page id appenndchild         
                        root.AppendChild(id);  // roots appenedchild
                        doc.AppendChild(root); //Main root

                    }

                }


             i++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("finished");
        Console.ReadKey();

        doc.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(path, ".xml"));

    }
```

Comment: you're totally right about changing the logic of the backup files , thing is i never made them , they were automatically made from a webpage as backup and now i need only the actual data and from 6000 files that i had i came up only with 1034 , so 1034 are the actual pages and the others are just history or backup files

Comment: Glad to know it has helped you. :)

Comment: I think I am the only one who thought it should be 0 with dot (.0) instead of just 0, but got a downvote... :D

Comment: haha iam sorry , tried to upvote you but i am still under 15 rep , means the public wont see , and .0 is sure the right answer because if 0 then 1 2 3 will remain

Comment: No worries.. Thanks.. :)